# Python pandas sort columns in csv by time with an interval of 5 minutes without rounding and sum

Tags: python, pandas, csv

A csv file with 600 thousand lines looks something like this.

| Time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-05 10:00:23 | 2 |
| 2022-07-05 10:01:11 | 5 |
| 2022-07-05 10:01:16 | 1 |
| 2022-07-05 10:01:33 | 2 |
| 2022-07-05 10:04:26 | 15 |
| 2022-07-05 10:05:57 | 1 |
| 2022-07-05 10:05:57 | 1 |
| 2022-07-05 10:05:57 | 3 |

And so on until 23:59:59

I'm trying something like

```py
def V_t_5_Min():
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(Ex_Csv,  usecols = ["Time", 'value']))
    a = df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
    b = df['value']
    c = pd.Series(a).dt.round("5T", 0)
    df = pd.DataFrame(c)
    df['value'] = b
    c = df.groupby('Time')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(c.sum())
    df1.to_csv('Datasets\CSV\V_5_min.csv')
```

But I get terrible rounding and incorrect calculations of the value

The desired result for an interval of 5 minutes

| Time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-05 10:05:00 | 30 |

and so on for every 5 minutes without rounding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `dt.ceil()` function to round up to the next 5 minute interval and then use a groupby to sum matching rows:

```py
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv',  usecols=["Time", 'value'], parse_dates=[0])
df['Ceil'] = df['Time'].dt.ceil("5T", 0)

print(df.groupby('Ceil').agg('sum'))
```

Giving you:

```
                     value
Ceil                      
2022-07-05 10:05:00     25
2022-07-05 10:10:00      5
```

The `parse_dates` parameter can be used to automatically convert the `Time` field into a datetime object.

Comment: Thank you very much! Apparently I'm doing something wrong since there is such a small solution.

Comment: Can you tell me please. How to make it so that with a second calculation, it jumps to the next minute at exactly 15:00:00. And did not sum up the values of 15:00:00 by 14:59:59?  That is, I have 15:00:00 values added to 14:59 minutes and 15:00:01 already go to the next minut. I'm trying your solution. 

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv',  usecols=["Time", 'value'], parse_dates=[0])
df['Ceil'] = df['Time'].dt.ceil("1T", 0)
#df['Ceil'] = df['Time'].dt.ceil("1T", 0)

print(df.groupby('Ceil').agg('sum'))

Comment: I'm not complete sure what you want, but perhaps what you need is `floor()` not `ceil()` ?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a code review first

```
def V_t_5_Min():
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(Ex_Csv,  usecols = ["Time", 'value']))
    a = df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
    b = df['value']
    c = pd.Series(a).dt.round("5T", 0)
    df = pd.DataFrame(c)
    df['value'] = b
    c = df.groupby('Time')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(c.sum())
    df1.to_csv('Datasets\CSV\V_5_min.csv')
```

What you could try to do - play around with the `custom_round` to achieve the desired rounding.

```
def custom_round(x):
    if x.minute % 10 == 5:
        # deal with the 10:05:xx case
        x = x.replace(minute=x.minute - 1)

    x = x.ceil('5T')
    return x


# data = [[e.strip() for e in line.split('|') if e.strip()]for line in data_.split("\n") if '---' not in line]
# df_ = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])
df_ = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(Ex_Csv,  usecols = ["Time", 'value']))
df_['Time'] = df_['Time'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df_['rounded_time'] = df_['Time'].apply(custom_round)
df_
```

this is the result from running the code on your data

```
    Time    value   rounded_time
0   2022-07-05 10:00:23 2   2022-07-05 10:05:00
1   2022-07-05 10:01:11 5   2022-07-05 10:05:00
2   2022-07-05 10:01:16 1   2022-07-05 10:05:00
3   2022-07-05 10:01:33 2   2022-07-05 10:05:00
4   2022-07-05 10:04:26 15  2022-07-05 10:05:00
5   2022-07-05 10:05:57 1   2022-07-05 10:05:00
6   2022-07-05 10:05:57 1   2022-07-05 10:05:00
7   2022-07-05 10:05:57 3   2022-07-05 10:05:00
```